# print usage on shell when running qsub without environment variable

Tags: shell, qsub

Is there a way to print the usage for a script on the terminal when submitting using qsub without any environment variable?

For eg, I have a script "script.sh" which should take 4 variables "var1, var2, var3 and var4". So the script should be submitted as `qsub -v var1=a,var2=b... script.sh`. I want to print what var1, var2.. etc refer to if the user tries to submit the job without any variable.

I know I can have a checkpoint inside the script and print it to a file, but I want to print the usage at the terminal itself when I try to submit the script.

Please let me know if I am unclear.

Thanks

Comment: either you `qsub` (script?) has to validate it's input or you need to create a shell script wrapper to do the job for you. I use something like `case $# in 4) qsub $1 $2 $3 $4 ;; * ) echo "usage msg"  >&2 ; exit 1 ;; esac` . with of course, `chmod +x myWrapperScript.sh`, before executing it. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the idea. the wrapper script makes sense and then I can make an alias, something like `alias qsub="bash ~/myWrapperScript.sh"`. will give it a shot. :)

Comment: Personnally I prefer a "she-bang" line at the top of my script file, `#!/bin/bash` (or change as needed to invoke the correct shell). Then you can drop the reference to `bash` in the alias. Otherwise you're on the right track. Good luck.

Comment: so what I actually did is, after the she-bang lines I put a check for hostname to see it is running from headnode. And then to print usage of the qsub script I run it with bash first.

Answer (score 0):

so what I actually did is, after the she-bang lines I put a check for hostname to see it is running from headnode. And then to print usage of the qsub script I run it with bash first.

```
if [ $HOSTNAME == "headnode" ]
then
    echo -e "Usage: ..."
    exit
fi
```